# Ruby Rails - how to update database with a calculation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a simple rails app. The user enters two separate integers and when they press 'create', the 'show' page displays the two values and a third value which is calculated from the user input.  I have put the arithmetic to calculate the third value in the 'show' html.erb view, but I can't work out how to add the third value into the database. Heres my code for the 'show' view:`

**Name:**
    <%= @startup.name %>

```
<p>
<strong>Revenue:</strong>
<%= @startup.revenue %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Costs:</strong>
<%= @startup.costs %>
</p>
<h2>
<strong>Profit:</strong>
<%= @startup.profit = @startup.revenue - @startup.costs %>
```

Comment: If you want to save `profit` into separate column, do it in model callback or in controller action. Views are not the best place to change model properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating Rails Fields Based on Calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261762/populating-rails-fields-based-on-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column to the database for this calculated value, and update it upon completing the calculation.

Create a migration to add the column `profit` to the `startup` model:

```
rails g migration AddProfitToStartups profit:decimal
```

with a note that you may choose a different datatype for `profit` depending on what datatype your `revenue` and `costs` columns are. There are other helpers for currency, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/what-is-the-best-method-of-handling-currency-money).

This will generate:

```
class AddProfitToStartups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :startups, :profit, :decimal
  end
end
```

now run `rake db:migrate` to update the database.

After this, the code you have in your view should work as is.

Answer (score -1):

Create a variable in the Startup model call profit.
In the create action have something like this:

```
def create
  @startup = Startup.new(startup_params)
  @startup.profit = @startup.revenue - @startup.costs
  @startup.save
  #redirect
end
```

Apparently the above answer is bad practice. So, here is what I hope is a better more general solution.

At the top of your Startup model have a call to before_save that will look like this:

```
before_save :calculate_profit
```

and then write a function in the Model called calculate profit. It will look something like this

```
def calculate_profit
  self.profit ||= self.revenue - self.costs
end
```

Comment: What if the object is manipulated via the console, or a rake task, or other model?

Comment: @BradWerth I didn't think of that

Comment: Thanks.  Works great "my" first bit of rails app logic!  However I put the above code (using self.)  into the model not the controller. 'before_save' only works in the model.